# using sql subtotals

Tags: sql

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT 
 c.compname AS [Company]
,x.Ressnavn AS [Client]
,a.jobid AS [Job Number]
,a.JobNavn AS [Job Name]
,t.TName [Task Name]
,cu.DayDate AS [Booking Date]
,cu.HrsBooked AS [Scheduled Hours]
,tr.Sale AS [Sales Value]
,(cu.HrsBooked) * (tr.Sale) AS [Total] 


FROM job a

    INNER JOIN jobplan jp on jp.JobId=a.jobid
    INNER JOIN JobDimensions AS z ON z.jobid = a.jobid
    INNER JOIN Ress AS x ON x.RessId = z.custid
    INNER JOIN JobPrice AS y ON y.JobId = a.Jobid
    INNER JOIN task t on t.PlanId = jp.PlanId
    INNER JOIN JobPriceactivity AS w ON w.priceId = y.priceId
    INNER JOIN taskres tr ON tr.TaskId = t.TaskId
    INNER JOIN emp e ON e.EmpId = tr.ResId
    INNER JOIN comp c ON e.compid = c.compid
    INNER JOIN CapUsed AS cu ON cu.RefId = tr.TaskResId AND cu.RefType=1 
    INNER JOIN arpaccount AS ar ON e.empname = ar.arpaccname
                                                            AND CAST (cu.DayDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate

WHERE c.compid = '107'  AND e.EMPID >='2' AND cu.HrsBooked > '0'

GROUP BY
x.Ressnavn 
,a.jobid  
,a.JobNavn  
,t.TName 
,cu.DayDate 
,cu.HrsBooked 
,y.priceid
,tr.Sale
,c.compname
```

That gives me the following output but I would like to add in a subtotal of the column 'Total' at each change in client.

An example of what I would like to try and get to is highlighted in green on the output screen grab.

[image: Output]

Can anyone advise on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `GROUP BY ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
    x.Ressnavn AS [Client],
    c.compname AS [Company],
    a.jobid AS [Job Number],
    a.JobNavn AS [Job Name],
    t.TName [Task Name],
    cu.DayDate AS [Booking Date],
    cu.HrsBooked AS [Scheduled Hours],
    tr.Sale AS [Sales Value],
    (cu.HrsBooked) * (tr.Sale) AS [Total]
FROM (...)
GROUP BY
    x.Ressnavn,
ROLLUP (
    c.compname,
    a.jobid,
    a.JobNavn,
    t.TName,
    cu.DayDate,
    cu.HrsBooked,
    y.priceid,
    tr.Sale )
```